# Does .NET takes advantage of multicore?

Tags: .net, multithreading, multicore

if I implemented a program with different threads working, can I rely .Net framework taking charge to execute threads taking advantage of (possible) multicore hardware architecture?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The OS should manage this and distribute the threads as it sees fit.

If you're using .NET 4 and want to take advantage of multicore CPUs, you can also look into the [Tasks Parallel Libary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717.aspx) which was created specifically to make parallel computing tasks easier to implement.

Comment: So, it OS that manage this stuff, or I've to learn task pattern? ;)

Answer (score 0):

This is the operating system's responsibility and yes, in the common case it will use multiple cores.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to take advantage for that architecture you must use .NET Framewrok 4.0 using Task Parallel Library

*System.Threading* 
*System.Threading.Tasks*

You must use tasks instead threads due to the tasks dynamically calculates if it needs to create different threads of execution or not.

Take a look on this [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/362996/Multi-core-programming-using-Task-Parallel-Library)

Answer (score 0):

The OS is responsible for supplying execution to threads.  The framework is a layer on top of the usual API calls and may supply extra multithreading functionality or simpler access.

Comment: Extra multithreading functionalities are not necessary for me. For me is enough to know that my multithread application in case of it run on multicore device can take advantage of these cores.